# GPUImage GPUImageRawDataOutput wrong output

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I've been using GPUImage to speed-up some scientific computations when I started to notice some strange return values when applying different filters. At first I assumed it was precision related but later on I noticed some strange effects:

When I use a a filter that is supposed to return binary results `{0,255}` such as `GPUImageLuminanceThresholdFilter` and then inspect the results pixel by pixel using `GPUImageRawDataOutput` I find different values as well. This happens only on iOS and not on OSX. At first I assumed it was random but after close inspection I noticed that it happens near the edges. My best guess is that when sampling the texture to return pixel values the samples are not located exactly in the pixel centers and some kind of interpolation occurs.

Is there an explanation for this behavior? How can I avoid it?

The size I use for `GPUImageRawDataOutput` result is the original image size.

Comment: Are you sure the pixel size is maintained throughout the processing pipeline, from input image to output? If using a GPUImagePicture for input, have you made sure smooth scaling (which uses mipmaps) is turned off? Have you made sure to account for any impact that a Retina display on the iOS device might have (making sure that pixels, not points, are used for size throughout)? This almost always is due to a size somewhere being a little off.

Comment: Pixel Size: YES. I didn't turn off smooth scaling but does it also cause smoothing of filter output? Regarding the retina display, pixels/points - I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: If you're using a GPUImagePicture, you need to set smoothlyScaleOutput to NO, otherwise the image is resampled to a power-of-two size for generating mipmaps. That will lead to image downsampling later on, and you won't get pixel-exact results. As far as Retina displays, there are several places where values are provided in points in UIKit, instead of pixels, and you will get 2 pixels per point for sizes specified in that manner. Check to make sure everything is specified in pixels throughout.

Comment: We decided to go back to CPU for now. I'll update on that one once we get the GPU code running again.